# Filemaker body auto resizing: Blank pages or cut content?

Tags: layout, filemaker

I am building a layout to print (PDFs) of letters. I understood that text fields can shrink automatically to avoid white spaces.

My layout body is about 10 pages high as this would be the longest possible letter. Problem is: I cannot figure out how to tell the body to shrink to one page if I have a one page letter only.

Thus, I end up having 9 empty pages (only page numbers) and one "real" page.

How can I avoid all the empty pages?

Comment: http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/create_layout.9.67.html#1030089

Answer (score 0):

If you have one enormous text field that you want to reduce in size based on the contents **and** have the enclosing part also reduce in size, look closely at the Position tab of the Inspector panel.

Under the "Sliding and Visibility" section, you'll find a checkbox for "Sliding up based on" with an additional pair of radio buttons and one checkbox when that's turned on. The checkbox reads "Also resize enclosing part". That's what you need to make sure is on to reduce the size of the body part the text field appears in.

[image]